# Removing an entire Parent node

Tags: xml, vba, parent-child, nodes

I have a XML file that contains multiple names and info about them:

```
<Male>
<LastName LName="Smith">
  <FirstName FName="Robert">
   <DateOfBirth DOB="9/15/1980">
      <MiddleName>Thomas</MiddleName>
      <Alias>bob</Alias>
      <Address>1234 S. Street Ave</Address>
   </DateOfBirth>
   </FirstName>
</LastName>
<LastName LName="Smith">
      <FirstName FName="Ted">
       <DateOfBirth DOB="7/21/1977">
          <MiddleName>James</MiddleName>
          <Alias>T</Alias>
          <Address>1234 N. Avanue St</Address>
       </DateOfBirth>
       </FirstName>
    </LastName>
```

Say for example I would Like to remove Ted Smith but keep Robert.

My code that I use is the following:

```
ind = ListBox1.Value 'Gets Lastname
ind2 = Me.ListBox1.Column(1, Me.ListBox1.ListIndex) 'Gets Firstname
ind3 = Me.ListBox1.Column(2, Me.ListBox1.ListIndex) 'Gets DOB

Set Remo = objDom.SelectNodes("//LastName[@LName='" & ind & "']/FirstName[@FName='" & ind2 & "']/DateOfBirth[@DOB='" & ind3 & "']")
For Each RemoG In Remo
RemoG.ParentNode.RemoveChild RemoG
Next
```

This will remove the DateOfBirth and everything under it, but it retains the FirstName and LastName information. How do I get it to remove them without removing the other Smith?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to navigate "up" to `<Male>` and remove from there

```
RemoG.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild RemoG.ParentNode.ParentNode
```